# Adding Binary Numbers in Java without using built in method?

Tags: java, binary

I'm messing around with Java and not sure why the end result in binary is adding an extra number than what's wanted. I want to print 8-bit, not more or less. I've tried different methods/ways, but still no luck. Here's what I have so far.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);


        int i,m,n,sum,carry=0;
     System.out.println("Enter your first binary number: "); 
                    int n1 = sn.nextInt();

                   System.out.println("Enter your second binary number: ");
                   int n2 = sn.nextInt();

                   for (i=arr.length-1;i>=0;i--){
                   m=n1%10;
                   n=n2%10;
                   n1=n1/10;
                   n2=n2/10;
                   sum=m+n+carry;

                         if (sum==1) {
                             arr[i]=1;
                             carry=0;
                            }

                            else if(sum==2) {
                              arr[i]=0;
                              carry=1;
                             }

                            else if(sum==3) {
                              arr[i]=1;
                              carry=1;
                             }

                            else {
                             arr[i]=m+n+carry;
                         }
                    }

                    for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                        System.out.print(arr[i]); 
                        }
                }
```

Comment: what is `arr` - how does your `for` loop even work?

Comment: shouldn't it be `else {arr[i] = 0; carry = 0;}`

Comment: In any language where I use binary I always use a filter to limit bit width.

Answer (score 0):

*In any language* where I use binary I always use a filter to limit bit width:
.arr[i]=m+n+carry&255;
 This may not be the full answer, just a basic stop-gap for bit overflow.
 No more than 8 bits can pass through this '&255' filter. Also it creates leading zero's if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your sum can be 0, 1, 2 or 3. You check for 1 to 3, so the `else` is for 0. The line there (`arr[i]=m+n+carry;`) is wrong, it should be `arr[i] = 0; carry = 0;`

Or just remove the whole `if` block to analyze `sum` and do the following:

```
carry = sum / 2; // integer division
arr[i] = sum % 2; // modulo
```